# How to create swipeable views in android?

Tags: android, android-animation, swipeview

I want to create a swipeable views in android.
My aim is to achieve this effect.

[image] [image]

Here, on swiping right i want to **change only image source**, **background image should be fixed**.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: try using view pager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ViewPager`, see [here](http://viewpagerindicator.com/).
You will have to modify it a bit.
Select a transparent background for the `ViewPager`, and set the background Image you need to the parent `View` of the `ViewPager`. The sample code for the implementation are [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample/SampleCirclesDefault.java) and also check the related xml files.